# Check e-mail function

Tags: javascript, forms, email

I'm trying to alert a message if the user doesn't complete the e-mail form. But its not working.

```
function reg_email_check() {
    var url = "/poll/email_check.php";
    var para = "email="+encodeURIComponent($F('email'));
    var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(
        url,
        {
            method: 'post',
            asynchronous: false,
            parameters: para,
            onComplete: return_email_check
        });
}
function return_email_check(req) {
    var msg = $('email_msg_id');
    var result = req.responseText;
    switch(result) {
        case '110' : msg.update('メールアドレスを正しく入力してください。').setStyle({ color: 'red' }); break;
        case '000' : msg.update('！このメールアドレスは登録済です。').setStyle({ color: 'red' }); break;
        case '130' : msg.update('このメールアドレスは登録可能です。 ').setStyle({ color: 'blue' }); break;
        default : alert( 'エラー.\n\n' + 'もう一度お試しください。' ); break;
    }
    //$('email_check').value=result;
}
```

What do I need to call here?

```
function checkfm()
{
    //ID関連スクリプト
    if(document.url.value.length==0)
    {
        alert("Insert e-mail");
        document.url.focus();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: "its not working" is not an obvious description, write the exact problem

Comment: I'd recommend checking your browser's log to see what is the result of the AJAX request. Please take a look: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools